# Как написать sql запрос для подсчёта доли?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь решить такую вот **задачу**:

Есть все данные о поездках на поезде. Одной поездке соответствует одна строка.
К каждой поездке привязан userid конкретного покупателя и все остальные его данные. Если у человека было несколько поездок, то его userid будет привязан к каждой из них.

При этом:
userid — числовое значение, id клиента из БД покупателей (например, 345)
date — дата поездки в формате DATETIME (пример, 2016-01-11 16:30:33)
city — город поездки (например, МОСКВА)

Нужен sql запрос, **отражающий долю пассажиров, которые за 2016 год совершали поездки 1-2 раза в месяц в один и тот же город.**

Насколько понимаю, все данные хранятся в одной таблице, но это и смущает, не могу разобраться, как прописать условие про поездки 1-2 раза в месяц в один и тот же город.
Помогите, пожалуйста, с запросом.

```
SELECT ((COUNT(userid WHERE ?))/ COUNT(DISTINCT userid))
FROM table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 0):

`` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND `city` = 'Moscow' ``